# rxjs - Filter stream events with boolean observable stream value

Tags: rxjs, observable

```
this.mainObservable$.pipe(
    iWantThisOperator(() => !this.theLatestObservableBooleanValue$)
).subscribe(() => {
    console.log('Stream Event')
})
```

"This not the actual code, I just want to describe it"

I want the operator that can handle to filter my mainObservable events depending on the latest observable stream boolean value

So I want all the mainObservable events only if theLatestObservableBooleanValue$ is false

Comment: you can use filter operator

Comment: filter is not for observables. filter is for another "flag" variable that can hold the status. I want to pass an observable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The [switchMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) operator**

*Use this if you just need the solution at one (or two) place(s)*

```js
const { Subject } = rxjs;
const { filter, switchMap } = rxjs.operators;

const condition$ = new Subject();
const main$ = new Subject();

const resultWithoutOperator$ = condition$.pipe(
  switchMap(condition => main$.pipe(filter(() => !condition)))
);

resultWithoutOperator$.subscribe(v =>
  console.log("#resultWithoutOperator$: ", v)
);

condition$.next(false);
main$.next(1);
condition$.next(true);
main$.next(2);
condition$.next(false);
main$.next(3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

**The custom operator**

*Use this if you need your behavior multiple times*

```js
const { Subject } = rxjs;
const { filter, switchMap } = rxjs.operators;

const condition$ = new Subject();
const main$ = new Subject();

function filterOperator(condition$) {
  return source$ => {
    return condition$.pipe(
      switchMap(condition => source$.pipe(filter(() => !condition)))
    );
  };
}

const resultWithOperator$ = main$.pipe(filterOperator(condition$));

resultWithOperator$.subscribe(v => console.log("#resultWithOperator$: ", v));

condition$.next(false);
main$.next(1);
condition$.next(true);
main$.next(2);
condition$.next(false);
main$.next(3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

**The custom operator with filter function as param**

*Use this if you need your behavior multiple times and want to be hardcore (or want to abstract the filter functionality)*

```js
const { Subject } = rxjs;
const { filter, switchMap } = rxjs.operators;

const condition$ = new Subject();
const main$ = new Subject();

function filterOperator(condition$, fn) {
  return source$ => {
    return condition$.pipe(
      switchMap(condition => source$.pipe(filter(() => fn(condition))))
    );
  };
}

const resultWithOperator$ = main$.pipe(filterOperator(condition$, v => !v));
const resultWithOperatorReverse$ = main$.pipe(filterOperator(condition$, v => v));

resultWithOperator$.subscribe(v => console.log("#resultWithOperator$: ", v));
resultWithOperatorReverse$.subscribe(v => console.log("#resultWithOperatorReverse$: ", v));

condition$.next(false);
main$.next(1);
condition$.next(true);
main$.next(2);
condition$.next(false);
main$.next(3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`withLatestFrom`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/withlatestfrom) to refer to the latest emitted value from another observable source.  Then, simply `filter` based on the other value, then `map` back to the "main" value:

```js
this.mainObservable$.pipe(
    withLatestFrom(this.theLatestObservableBooleanValue$),
    filter(([main, boolean]) => !boolean),
    map(([main]) => main)
  ).subscribe(n => {
      console.log(`Stream Event ${n}`)
  })
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66525006?file=index.ts).

If you wanted to make this into your own custom operator, it could look something like this:

```js
function iWantThisOperator(boolean$: Observable<boolean>) {
  return function<T>(source$: Observable<T>) {
    return source$.pipe(
      withLatestFrom(boolean$),
      filter(([, boolean]) => !boolean),
      map(([source]) => source)
    )
  }
}

mainObservable$.pipe(
    iWantThisOperator(theLatestObservableBooleanValue$)
).subscribe(() => {
    console.log('Stream Event')
})
```